# Как убрать относительные пути в коде?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть dom-дерево файла html.
В файле прописаны относительные пути к файлам стилей, картинкам, скриптам, например:

```
href="../../css/reset.css"
href="../../../styles/owl.carousel.css"
href="../styles/jquery.arcticmodal.css"
href="../styles/animate.css"

src="../images/slider__slide1_image.jpg"
src="../images/slider__slide2_image.jpg"
```

Как сделать так, чтобы все пути стали вида

```
href="css/reset.css"
href="styles/owl.carousel.css"
href="styles/jquery.arcticmodal.css"
href="styles/animate.css"

src="images/slider__slide1_image.jpg"
src="images/slider__slide2_image.jpg"
```

С помощью какого регулярного выражения это можно сделать?

Comment: Можно от рута ссылки писать, начиная со слэша, и будут получше ссылки, а прчем тут регулярные выражения?

Comment: Нужно просто положить эти файлы на уровень/уровни выше. Тогда и пути будут проще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '
    href="../../css/reset.css"
    href="../../../styles/owl.carousel.css"
    href="../styles/jquery.arcticmodal.css"
    href="../styles/animate.css"

    src="../images/slider__slide1_image.jpg"
    src="../images/slider__slide2_image.jpg"
';

echo preg_replace('/="\K[\/.]+/', '', $string);
```

https://regex101.com/r/TquU6q/1

https://3v4l.org/nTEKZ